# Smooth transition one gesture to another. How to force start touchesbegan when finger already pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, gestures, touchesbegan

I am trying to achieve the following in xcode:  One a pan gesture has reached a certain point, I want to draw a draggable item, and have the user's finger automatically keep dragging it around to move the new item.  Everything works, except for one problem: The finger needs to be picked up and put down again on the new item when it is initially drawn (I assume to trigger touchesbegan).

Does anyone know if there is a way to force start touchesbegan if the finger is already pressed when the newly drawn item is first rendered (so the user doesn't have to pick up and put down his finger)?

Comment: I am not sure what you want to do. Do you want to drag an item and put somewhere?

Comment: The original pan gesture is in a cell in a tableview. When it gets to a certain point, I draw a UIButton subclass. The newly drawn UIButton has "draggable" ability (per many examples shown separately) using TouchesBegan/Moved.  Imagine dragging the cell to the right (pan), the button appears right under your finger (maybe I should have been clearer about that), and you keep dragging your finger and move the button to wherever you want.  It works, but the user needs to pick up his finger and put it down again once the button appears or it won't move (unless you "re-press" the button).

Comment: The button looks like one of the cells. The idea is to create the illusion of dragging a cell out into the view space. I should add, I tried to disable the original pan gesture after I drew the button, but that still didn't "start" the "draggable" (touchesbegan) code in the UIButton.

Comment: I don't understand what is your problem. Are you not able to DROP the button or not able to MOVE the button along with finger?

Comment: The gesture recognizer will cancel your touch events (your touches did cancel is also called).. Is there an option for you to create your own panning through touch events (no gestures) or simply continue using pan gesture to move the newly created view?

Comment: Matic, thank you, I was able to continue the gesture and duplicated the move button code to use during that first continued gesture.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. @MaticOblak how did you solve this?

Comment: First set the "cancelsTouchesInView" property on the pan gesture to NO so you receive event for the gestures and the touch events. Second in your pan gesture event method go to the part you add the subview and insert gesture.enabled = NO;gesture.enabled = YES; this way you brake the current gesture. Now at this point just keep a reference of the subview you wish to move and continue its code in "touchesMoved". I hope this helps.